# How to dequeue and display queue?

Tags: python, queue

I have learn python for a while and I have some questions. How can I dequeue and display queue? Also, other function may have some problem. Here is my code. I am using google colab.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self) :
        # implement a queue with an array
        self.stack = []
        self.size = 0

    def enqueue(self, data):
        # insert data at the end of queue
        self.stack.append(data)
        self.size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        # take out data at the beginning of the queue
        if(self.size > 0):
            self.size -= 1
            return self.stack.dequeue
        else:
            return("")
        # remove it and return the data taken out

    def display(self):
        # show all the data in the queue
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        # implement a queue with an array
        self.stack = []
        self.size = 0
    def enqueue(self, data):
        # insert data at the end of queue
        self.stack.append(data)
        self.size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        # take out data at the beginning of the queue
        if(self.size > 0):
            self.size -= 1
            return self.stack.pop(0)
        else:
            return None
        # remove it and return the data taken out

    def display(self):
        # show all the data in the queue
        if(self.size > 0):
            for i in range(self.size):
                print(self.stack[i])

q = Queue()
for i in range(3):
    q.enqueue(i)

q.display()
print('dequeue : ',q.dequeue())
q.display()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.